# How to get versionCode of app outside my own?

Tags: java, android, json, version

I am attempting to add a function to that will check a json file on my server for the versionCode of an app outside of my own and if the versionCode in json on the server is **greater than** the one of the app outside of my own, then do an update action.

The update action works fine, however, I am experiencing issues getting the versionCode of the outside app. The versionCode always returns as 0 instead of the actual version of the outside app.

> Why doesn't it return the proper version?

Here is my code for fetching the versionCode of the other app:

```
public static int getinstVersionCode(Context mContext) {
    if (mContext != null) {
        try {
            return mContext.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(Constants.PACKAGE_NAME, 0).versionCode;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException ignored) {
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The PACKAGE_NAME equals the com.example.app app package name that is held in the json file on my server:

```
static final String APK_VERSION_CODE = "versionCode";
static final String PACKAGE_NAME = "package";
```

And finally, the json file itself:

```
"versionCode":0,
"package":"com.example.app",
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the exception, the application which version you are trying to get must be present on the device and exactly match the package name.

Comment: Even when I set the package name in the json on my server to my own apk it only returns 0. The package name is correct

Comment: Try to put something you are certain that will return the version different from 0 for example "com.android.chrome".